# Error 70: Permission denied running my app at startup

Tags: vb6, registry, startup

I've made an example using this function:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function RegCloseKey Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hKey As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RegOpenKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegOpenKeyExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpSubKey As String, ByVal ulOptions As Long, ByVal samDesired As Long, phkResult As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RegSetValueEx Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegSetValueExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpValueName As String, ByVal Reserved As Long, ByVal dwType As Long, lpData As Any, ByVal cbData As Long) As Long

Private Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER     As Long = &H80000001
Private Const KEY_WRITE             As Long = &H20006
Private Const REG_SZ                As Long = &H1

Public Function PutOnStartUp(ByVal sPath As String) As Boolean
Dim hRegkey                         As Long

    If RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", 0, KEY_WRITE, hRegkey) = 0 Then
        sPath = sPath & vbNullChar
        PutOnStartUp = RegSetValueEx(hRegkey, "My App", 0, REG_SZ, ByVal sPath, Len(sPath)) = 0
        RegCloseKey hRegkey
    End If
End Function
```

---

**TEST ONE:**

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim sPath      As String

    sPath = App.Path & "\" & App.EXEName & ".exe"
    
    If PutOnStartUp(sPath) Then
        Me.BackColor = vbGreen
    Else
        Me.BackColor = vbRed
    End If
    
    Me.AutoRedraw = True
    Me.Print sPath
End Sub
```

- I compile it on the desktop.
- I execute it.
- I restart the PC and effectively executed successfully from my desktop.

---

**TEST TWO:**

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim sPath      As String
Dim sDest      As String

    sPath = App.Path & "\" & App.EXEName & ".exe"
    sDest = Environ("tmp") & "\Test.exe"

    If sDest <> sPath Then
        FileCopy sPath, sDest
    
        If PutOnStartUp(sDest) Then
            Me.BackColor = vbGreen
        Else
            Me.BackColor = vbRed
        End If
    End If

    Me.AutoRedraw = True
    Me.Print sPath
End Sub
```

- I compile it on my desktop.
- I execute it.
- I check that it was copied to the temporary folder.
- I delete the exe of my desktop.
- I reboot and... **¡CRASH!**

> Error 70: Permission denied

What happens here?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions on the temp folder. As I understand it by googling the issue, running programs from the temp folder is restricted because many malware programs run from it.